# RPI3 - Onboard PSU 230VAC to 12/5VDC?

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, 12v, 5v

I'm thinking of creating a project with a RPI3 and LED strip for home automation. And I want it to keep it as «clean» as possible, less cable mess is better. The RGB LED strip is working at 12VDC, and the RPI3 works at 5VDC.

So I was thinking of soldering a PCB that fits on top of the RPI3 GPIO pins, the PCB should contain 230VAC to 12/5VDC PSU and RGB LED driver (3 MOSFET's).

The question is about the PSU, is it a good idea to mount a switched 230VAC PSU ontop og the RPI3? Or can it be dangerous?

Comment: It's a bad idea because people tend to use heatsinks on their RPi3, and people tend not to use the bolts to secure a hat mechanically but rely solely on the connector. The same, they will not put the required insulation sheet inbetween. Uh, and — how are **you** going to handle the required insulation spacing between the 230V and the 12/5V part in such a small space? An experienced engineer could create such a thing, but most likely, won't.

Comment: Please, this is one of the things that if you have to ask you definitely should not do. It is very dangerous for you and other people, you could die or go to jail. Just don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be death-courtlingly dangerous. Also, mains to d.c. PSUs are not simple to design. There are a lot of things to consider including creepage and clearance rules and plenty to learn about.

If you were to do it, you'd need to mount the whole system in box that humans can't touch, ensure that the mains voltages have appropriate clearances from the RPi GPIO pins and make it very robust.

You can get very neat little PCB mount mains to 12V modules these days, but they are low power and almost definitely not enough for what you want.

I would be more tempted to use a 5V step-up to 12V d.c. to d.c converter if the LED power budget was modest enough (or even better use Maz's idea below!).

Comment: Or alternatively use off the shelf 12V supply and then use buck (or even linear supply) to go down to 5V. 12V supplies are popular and if bought from reputable source would be safe.

Comment: @maz, yep, good point. Better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not good idea to mount power supply above GPIO pins.

Instead buy a external hardrive power supply which has 12V/5V rails which you can use to power both Raspberry PI and LED strip from single supply it will also not look 'messy'.